# Displaying the data (retrieved from an API call) after user submit the form without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a form that will get a search query request from the user on submit and will display the results after making an API call I would like to show the results without refreshing the page using AJAX. I am using PHP to connect to the API.

This is what I have so far but I can't get the results displayed. Regardless of the success of the API connection, I cant even get the entry of the form displayed in the same page without refreshing the page so I am not sure if I am doing it right. what am I missing? What else do I have to consider in order to make this work? Could someone please guide me to the right direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#search-form').on('submit', (function(e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({

            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

              console.log(data);

              $('#results').html(data);
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

```html
<form action='result.php' method='post' id='search-form'>
  <input type='search' name='search'>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='results'>Result comes here..</div>
```

// result.php

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $query = urlencode( $_POST[ "search"]);
    $request = 'http://some.api/?query=' . $query;
    $response=file_get_contents($request); 
    $result=json_decode($response); 

    echo ($result);
} else {
    echo ("No search query has received");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` does not serialize submit buttons. Submit buttons are only sent in requests when they are pressed/trigger the submit action on the form they are in, `.serialize()` has no way of knowing any of that.
You'll just have to add that information manually or not check for it at all.

```
...
data: $(this).serialize()='&submit=ajax',
...
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST['search'])) {
...
```

Comment: How about this? 

if(isset($_POST['search']) {
     
     $query = urlencode( $_POST[ "search"]);
    $request = 'http://some.api/?query=' . $query;
     $response=file_get_contents($request); 
     $result=json_decode($response); 

     echo ($result);
 } else {
     echo ("No search query has received");
 }

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in this case, you just create a hidden field with the value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="submitted" />
```

And that's going to be there on a submit.